# Crispy forms text input height (Django 1.9)

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

My input text fields rendered with crispy forms are way too tall. In all the examples I see most text fields have a height of just one character (that is what I want). But my input fields are much higher. 
I am using bootstrap3.
(see attached image)[image]

My base template has nothing special as far as I can see. Here's the main part:

```
      <body class="skin-black">
    <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
    <header class="header">
        <a href="/" class="logo">
        <img src="{% static 'portal/logo.png' %}" alt="Logo"/>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
            <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout {{ user.username }} </a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="/registration/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
            <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
                <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
                <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
                    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                        <div class="user-panel"></div>
                    </section>
                       <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <div id="MainMenu">
                          <div class="list-group panel">
                              {% for group in user.groups.all %}
                                {% if not group.name == 'client' %}
                                    <a href="/" class="list-group-item">Home</a>
                                    <a href="/modules" class="list-group-item">Modules</a>
                                {% endif %}
                              {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    </aside>

            <aside class="right-side">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="row">
                            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>


            <div class="footer-main navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer">
                Copyright &copy NOZHUP, 2016
            </div>
            </aside><!-- /.right-side -->


    </div>
```

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import Module, Category, Case
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Field, Fieldset, ButtonHolder
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import (
    PrependedText, PrependedAppendedText, FormActions)



class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModuleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        #self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        #self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-2'
        #self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Enter module name, version and description',
                'name',
                'version',
                'description'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields=('name', 'version', 'description')

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'save'))

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields=('name',)
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    version = models.TextField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    action = models.TextField(null=True)
    desiredresult = models.TextField(null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Suite(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    cases = models.ManyToManyField(Case)
    untested = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    passed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    failed = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

module_edit.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h4>Modules</h4>
{% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post the code for your form class.

Comment: You need to post the `forms.py` class and the `models.py` class. It is likely that you are using the wrong widget for rending the component. Also, if you are using crispy forms, I cannot find `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` in the template you posted. Which means you are not using crispy forms for the rendering

Comment: @Cheng: As you can see I use the tag in a subtemplate...

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using `models.TextField` instead of `models.CharField` by mistake. Usually models mostly have `CharField` and only some of the few fields are `TextField`. `TextField` is for longer, possibly multi line, potentially rich text content. I doubt that you would want the `Module` `name` or `Module` `version` to be multi-line. Even the `description` may not need that (your business need can tell that).

What textual input fields you usually see in tutorials are `<input type="text"`s rendered for `CharField`s. What you have are `textarea`s rendered for your `TextField`s, and they supposed to naturally look like that (10 rows and 40 columns by default I think). In that case you can still influence how many rows and columns the textarea shows at a time (but the editable content can be much longer):

```
self.fields['description'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 25})
```

This is standard Django BTW, and crispy form picks it up.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!